# How to remove duplicate values from list of dicts and keep original order?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like this :

```
time_array_final = [{'day': 15, 'month': 5},{'day': 29, 'month': 5}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 14, 'month': 6},{'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}]
```

I want to remove the duplicate dictionaries from this list. Here is what I tried:

```
import ast
final  = [ast.literal_eval(el1) for el1 in set([str(el2) for el2 in time_array_final])]
```

eventually it's working but there is issue I want to retain this data in its original order but the order is modified in my output. Is there a way to remove duplicates and maintain the order from the original list?

**Note:**  **expected output** should be unique and in case of repeating it should pick one record from repeating elements as the code doing above      for example in this case output should be

```
[{'day': 15, 'month': 5},{'day': 29, 'month': 5},{'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 14, 'month': 6},{'day': 15, 'month': 6}]
```

Comment: It would really help if you provided info what you got and what you expect, along with a minimal set of input data that illustrates this, a.k.a. [mcve].

Comment: Maybe if you had formatted your data with one dict per line so that it's readable, more people would've noticed that it's sorted, could've asked about that, and could've written better solutions taking advantage of that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary where the key is the string representation of the items in your list, and the value is the actual item.

```
time_array_final = [{'day': 15, 'month': 5},{'day': 29, 'month': 5}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 14, 'month': 6},{'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}]

dedupe_dict = {str(item): item for item in time_array_final}
```

Upon encountering a duplicate item, the dict comprehension will overwrite the previous item with the duplicate one, but that doesn't make any material difference because both items are identical.

Since python 3.6, [dictionaries keep insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/843953), so `dict.values()` should give you the output you need.

```
deduped_list = list(dedupe_dict.values())
```

Which gives:

```
[{'day': 15, 'month': 5},
 {'day': 29, 'month': 5},
 {'day': 10, 'month': 6},
 {'day': 12, 'month': 6},
 {'day': 14, 'month': 6},
 {'day': 15, 'month': 6}]
```

---

As noted by [@Copperfield](/u/5644961) in their [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648520/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-list-of-dicts-and-keep-original-order/72648911?noredirect=1#comment128330239_72648746) on another answer, `str(dict)` is not the most reliable way of stringifying dicts for comparison, because the order of keys matters.

```
d1 = {'day': 1, 'month': 2}
d2 = {'month': 2, 'day': 1}

d1 == d2 # True
str(d1) == str(d2) # False
```

To get around this, you could create a `frozenset` of the `dict.items()`, and use that as your key (provided all the values in your dict are hashable) like so:

```
dedupe_dict = {frozenset(d.items()): d for d in time_array_final}
```

Comment: why string conversion? in this particular example it might work, but it will fail if the dict happens to be build in a different order same as I mention to @TimurShtatland

Comment: @Copperfield good point. I modified my answer to include your suggestion

Comment: For the `frozenset` method, you'd still need to unpack it back to the original formatting with something like `list(map(dict, dedupe_dict))` no?

Comment: @BeRT2me no, because the frozensets are the _keys_ in that dictionary. The values are still the original dictionaries, and that's what we use in `deduped_list = list(dedupe_dict.values())`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to keep track of unique items. The items are converted to strings because dictionaries cannot be hashed in a set (otherwise, you will get an error "`TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`"). Iterate over the original list, adding the element only if its string representation was not already seen.

```
time_array_final = [{'day': 15, 'month': 5},{'day': 29, 'month': 5}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 14, 'month': 6},{'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}]

time_array_final_unique = []
time_array_final_set = set()

for d in time_array_final:
    if str(d) not in time_array_final_set:
        time_array_final_unique.append(d)
        time_array_final_set.add(str(d))
print(time_array_final_unique)
# [{'day': 15, 'month': 5}, {'day': 29, 'month': 5}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 14, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}]
```

Comment: hi sir thanks for answer but seems there is a problem records are missing in output  for example   {'day': 12, 'month': 6} , {'day': 15, 'month': 6}  etc .  as these are repeating then I want these as single record .

Comment: OP seems to want to de-duplicate their list, not get unique items

Comment: I have updated question kindly check with sample output @PranavHosangadi

Comment: why string conversion?

Comment: @Copperfield: I added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: sure, but if for whatever reason the dict happens to by build in a different order it will fail to remove that duplicate, like for example: `(str({'day': 15, 'month': 5}) == str({'month': 5, 'day': 15}))==False`

Comment: a more reliable way to transform a dict into something that can be use in a set is to use a frozenset (which is an immutable set, and as such can be inside a set) over the items of the dictionary (so long the values are also hashable), `frozenset({'day': 15, 'month': 5}.items()) == frozenset({'month': 5, 'day': 15}.items())`

Answer (score 0):

as an addendum to @BeRT2me answer, you can go a step further and use the [ListBaseSet](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#examples-and-recipes) recipe you can find in the standard library

```
import collections

class ListBasedSet(collections.abc.Set):
    ''' Alternate set implementation favoring space over speed
        and not requiring the set elements to be hashable. '''
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.elements = lst = []
        for value in iterable:
            if value not in lst:
                lst.append(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.elements)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self.elements

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.elements)
```

put it in your toolkit and use is simple like

```
>>> time_array_final = [{'day': 15, 'month': 5},{'day': 29, 'month': 5}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 14, 'month': 6},{'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}, {'day': 15, 'month': 6}]
>>> 
>>> expected=[{'day': 15, 'month': 5},{'day': 29, 'month': 5},{'day': 10, 'month': 6}, {'day': 12, 'month': 6}, {'day': 14, 'month': 6},{'day': 15, 'month': 6}]
>>> 
>>> expected == list(ListBasedSet(time_array_final))
True
>>>
```

Comment: yes, is the same idea, the recipe just add the Set functionality if that is of interest

Comment: @BeRT2me I gets it, I even upvote it if that make you feel better...